# Google cloud platform computing engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Recently I used Google cloud platform computing engine to create a Windows machine and connected to it via remote desktop. When I do not want to work on it, I must disconnect or shutdown the machine? since its cost per hour decreases from my credit free $300. 
I am afraid to try disconnect or shutdown and become did not able to connect to it again.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make sure to shut down any Compute Engine instances (in your case, the Windows virtual machine) that you're not actively using if you don't want to be charged for them. Disconnecting from Remote Desktop is not enough, as the instance will still be running. Do not worry about being able to restart it again. Google Cloud makes that really easy to do.

When you want to start your instance back up, go to the Google Cloud console (https://console.cloud.google.com). Since you can have multiple projects, and since you can create different virtual machines in different projects, you must make sure you're in the correct project. In the blue title bar to the right of the "Google Cloud Platform" banner click the dropdown list to select your project (if you're new to GCP you will probably only have one project to choose from). Next click the hamburger menu (the three horizontal lines in the upper left corner) and choose "Compute Engine". That will bring you to a screen that will show you all of your Compute Engine instances. Click on the checkbox to the left of the instance, and from the toolbar to the right of the title "VM instances" click the triangle icon (when you hover over it, a tooltip will pop up that reads "Start"). A window will pop up warning you that you will be billed for the running instance. Click "Start". You will see a circle start to spin next to your instance. Once it turns into a green checkmark, your virtual machine is running. Then you can click on "RDP" to connect to your remote desktop session.

Again, unless you want to keep your virtual machine running to service clients, be sure to shut it down when you're done so that you minimize the cost.

Google Cloud offers a lot of free and low-cost services, so it's a great way to learn about cloud computing! Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful answer!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!